# Accuracy in the sum of an array of NSNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, double, nsnumber, floating-accuracy

I have an array of NSNumber (in this case, for simplicity I have only one element)

The array is "_incassiInDistinta" that contains an object "Incasso" which has a property "_importoIncassato"

[image]

Now if I use this

```
double sum = [[_incassiInDistinta valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.importoIncassato"] doubleValue];
```

the variable "sum" I is valued as follows:

[image]

If you run the sum by this method the variable "sum" that is this:

```
NSArray *importi = [_incassiInDistinta valueForKeyPath:@"importoIncassato"];
__block double sum = 0;
[importi enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *op, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    sum = sum + [op doubleValue];
}];
```

[image]

How do I get the right values​​?
thanks

EDIT:

I have to compare the sum variable in an if

if (sum> = 1373.63) .....

does not work

Comment: Tested your code. I got same result for both ways. Make sure that variable `_importoIncassato` is rounded properly.

Comment: _importoIncassato only has 2 decimal places (a value read from the database and converted into nusumber)

Answer (score 1):

Your discrepancy is just due to binary approximations of float values, about 1e-13 between your two results don't worry about it. An article about float representations [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

If you actually need exact decimal numbers (for currency for example), you can use NSDecimalNumber. But only use them if really necessary, they make everything a lot slower.

Comment: wrong, because in the first case I have to compare the sum variable in an if

if (sum> = 1373.63) .....

does not work

Comment: If you need exact decimal values, use NSDecimalNumber

Comment: thank you for your explanation, I feel the NSDecimalNumber, even if it annoys me because I'm in a cycle

Comment: NSDecimalNumber does make things more cumbersome, but every time you use exact equality checks with floats you are exposing yourself to rounding error problems

Answer (score 0):

It's a hack i have used for issue like above.

Convert `double` to `NSString` with round up to two decimal points.

Then again convert it to `double` from `NSString`. This will give you result you required. Try it.

```
NSString *roundUp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",sum];

double finalValue = [roundUp doubleValue];

double fixValue = 1373.63;

if (finalValue == fixValue) {
    NSLog(@"Both values are same");
}
```

Comment: This won't change the fact that your final value will not be an exact decimal representation

Comment: It might, but NSDecimalNumber is there to handle exactly this problem, more safely and elegantly

Comment: @jbat100 Check edited answer, Show comparison for both values.

Comment: @jbat100 You are right about `NSDecimalNumber`, And as i said it is a hack :)